# Did Hadrat Muhammad (SAW) have a slave or not?

Tags: slavery

It was narrated from Anas, that the Messenger of Allah had a female slave with whom he had intercourse, but 'Aishah and Hafsah would not leave him alone until he said that she was forbidden for him. Then Allah, the Mighty and Sublime, revealed:
"O Prophet! Why do you forbid (for yourself) that which Allah has allowed to you.' until the end of the Verse.

https://sunnah.com/nasai:3959

Narrated 'Amir bin Al-Harith:
Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) did not leave a Dinar or a Dirham or a male or a female slave. He left only his white mule on which he used to ride, and his weapons, and a piece of land which he gave in charity for the needy travelers.

https://sunnah.com/bukhari:4461

Are these contradictions? Cause first says that there was a female slave and second says there was no male or female slave.

Answer (score 1):

It is not contradictory because the first hadith only implies that the Prophet ﷺ had at least one concubine for at least some part of his life, whereas the second hadith asserts that he had not left any slaves at the time of his death. There are a number of possible explanations which can lead to this:

- The slave was automatically freed at the death of the Prophet ﷺ. The slave meant in the first hadith is Mariyah al-Qibtiyyah, she had given birth to a son of the Prophet ﷺ named Ibrahim. Under Islamic law such a slave becomes free automatically at the death of her master:

  > نهى رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم عن بيع أمهات الأولاد , لا يبعن ولا يوهبن ولا يورثن , يستمتع بها سيدها ما بدا له فإذا مات فهي حرة
  >
  > The Messenger of Allah ﷺ forbade the sale of the (slave) mothers of one's children, they can not be sold, nor gifted, nor inherited. Her master will have intimacy with her while he is alive and when he dies she shall be free.
  >
  > <sup>— [Sunan al-Daraqutni](https://shamela.ws/book/9771/3984)</sup>

  Hence the second hadith does not count her as a slave because she had become free.
- The Prophet ﷺ might have freed and released the slave before his death.
- The slave herself might have died before the death of the Prophet ﷺ.

**Ref:**

> وفيه دلالة على أن من ذكر من رقيق النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم في جميع الأخبار كان إما مات وإما أعتقه واستدل به على عتق أم الولد بناء على أن مارية والدة إبراهيم بن النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم عاشت بعد النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم وأما على قول من قال إنها ماتت في حياته صلى الله عليه وسلم فلا حجة فيه
>
> <sup>— [Fath al-Bari](https://shamela.ws/book/1673/3142)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The second hadith is about the time of the Prophet's death because it says:

> did not leave

So, it is talking about the heir of Prophet A.S.

Also, if the Prophet (peace be upon him) had any slaves, he would free them and not keep them as slaves for a long time.